# Need to get Line number of Select-String mactch

Tags: powershell, line-numbers, select-string

realy need your help.

I have a $combobox that gives me all the FileName that contain "wrong source".

<$ComboBox.Items.AddRange(@(Get-ChildItem $filepath -Recurse -Include "*.xml", "*.txt"| Select-String "wrong source" -List | select-Object FileName))>

I need to get the line number on the file where that match occurred.

I have been looking and nothing works. Can you help?

Comment: Instead of `select-Object FileName` try `Select-Object -Property *` at least once. 

Comment: `Get-Member` is your friend. Use it to find out what kind of object(s) are flowing throught the pipeline and their members. `Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.xml' | Get-Member` Also, `Format-List` will dump the contents.

Answer (score 0):

To search for the string "wrong source" in XML and TXT files and populate a ComboBox with the filenames and line numbers where matches are found, this should do:

• Populate the ComboBox with filename and line number directly within the ForEach-Object block:

```
# Search the given $filepath recursively for files with .xml or .txt extension
Get-ChildItem $filepath -Recurse -Include "*.xml", "*.txt" | 

# Use Select-String to find the first instance of "wrong source" in each file
Select-String "wrong source" -List | 

# For each matching line, execute the script block
ForEach-Object {
    # Add a new item to the ComboBox with the filename and line number of the match
    $comboBox.Items.Add("$($_.FileName) - Line: $($_.LineNumber)")
}
$comboBox.Items.Add("$($_.FileName) - Line: $($_.LineNumber)")
}
```

Comment: The expression `$ComboBox.Items.AddRange(@($_))` is not a valid downstream pipeline command element (you can't _pipe_ directly to it). Move it into the `ForEach-Object` block and remove the following `|`